# Android Task AsyncTask issue with postExec

Tags: android, android-asynctask

the Problem I am having is that the PostExecute is not firing. 
I see the log tag for background but P.E. never fires.

I am invoking this task from a timer like this:

```
      findViewById(R.id.buttonstart).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    openFile("FeedTimerTask.html");
                    Timer t = new Timer("FeedTimerTask", true);
                    timerTask = new FeedTimerTask();
                    t.schedule(timerTask, 2000, 20000);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

Runnable runme = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            timestart = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(); 
            provider.refreshNoCache();


        }
    };

     class FeedTimerTask extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{Looper.prepare();}catch(Exception e){};
            runme.run();

        }

     }
```

Here is the main  task itself from inside the dataprovider  class invoked with "provider.refreshNoCache();" above:

```
// threaded rteftesh tasks
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class RefreshTask extends SupportAsyncTask {

    private int errorcodecode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog=null;
    private Exception mainExeption=null;
    protected  String waitMessage = "Laddar ner information..";
    private boolean useCache;

    public RefreshTask(boolean useCache) {
        this.useCache = useCache;
    }

    public void onPreExecute() {
        data = null;
        if (showSpinnerOnRefresh){
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", waitMessage , true);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        errorcodecode = 1;
            try {
                invokeFeedRead();
                Log.e("DataProvider", "Bkgtask...");
                errorcodecode = 0;
            } catch (BrJSONException e) {
                Log.e("[ERROR]","PROVIDER "+e.getMessage());
                mainExeption = e;
                errorcodecode = 1;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("[ERROR]","PROVIDER "+e.getMessage());
                mainExeption = e;
                errorcodecode = 2;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("[ERROR]","PROVIDER "+e.getMessage());
                mainExeption = e;
                errorcodecode = 3;
            }

        if (errorcodecode==0){ 
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {

        super.onCancelled();
        Log.e("DataProvider", "Cancelled...");

        if (dialog != null)
            try{dialog.dismiss();}catch(Exception e){}
        BrAlert.Show(context, "Obs", BrAppConfig.ServerError+" (timeout)", 0);
        onError_IO(new IOException("Timeout!"));
        errorcodecode=2;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        // super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("DataProvider", "PostExec...");

        if (dialog != null)
            try{dialog.dismiss();}catch(Exception e){}

        switch (errorcodecode) {
        case 0:
            onFeedLoaded();             
            cacheAge = System.currentTimeMillis();
            break;
        case 1:
            onError_DataFormat(mainExeption);
            break;
        case 2:
            onError_IO(mainExeption);
            break;
        default:
            onError_GeneralExeption(mainExeption);

        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is cancelled even before it reached onPostExecte method. If the task is cancelled before it reaches onPostExecute Method. It will not trigger onPostExecute but trigger onCancelled Method. Please provide enough time to finish the task.

Comment: Thing is, the OnCancelled event is not firing either, i see nothing in the log.

Comment: Thanks, your comment lead me to thinking about thread scope, and i solved it. Answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem in the end. It was to do with the scope.
I needed a handler to invoke the other thread.

Here is the solution for others may find helpful:

in on create:

```
                tickHandler = new Handler();
                tickTimer = new Timer();
                tickTimer.schedule(new FeedTimerTask(),
                               0,
                               50000);  //FPS
```

The handler class.

```
    class FeedTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    private Runnable runable;

    public FeedTimerTask(){
        super();
        runable = new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                timestart = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(); 
                provider.refreshNoCache();

            }

        };
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tickHandler.post(runable);

    }

}
```